# Is there any security settings in Windows that block Powershell scripts that change registry?

Tags: windows, powershell, security

I would like create a Powershell script that will modify registry key to fix the MS13-098 vulnerability.

Below is the script, it has 2 parts:

1-create the registry file

2-import the registry file

The scripts it works locally but when we pushed via **Automox Worklet** or **Dameware**, only step 1 works, step 2 doesn't work.

I wonder if there is any security settings in Windows that block Powershell scripts that change registry?

```
$ScriptAlreadyRun = Test-Path "C:\Tempt\Reg\patch.reg"

if (!($ScriptAlreadyRun)) {
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\Tempt\Reg 
New-Item "C:\Tempt\Reg\patch.reg" -ItemType File -Value ""
Add-Content "C:\Tempt\Reg\patch.reg" "Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00"
Add-Content "C:\Tempt\Reg\patch.reg" "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Wintrust\Config]"
Add-Content "C:\Tempt\Reg\patch.reg" "`"EnableCertPaddingCheck`"=`"1`""
Add-Content "C:\Tempt\Reg\patch.reg" ""
Add-Content "C:\Tempt\Reg\patch.reg" "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography\Wintrust\Config]"
Add-Content "C:\Tempt\Reg\patch.reg" "`"EnableCertPaddingCheck`"=`"1`""
 
regedit /s import C:\Tempt\Reg\patch.reg
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you making sure that your script is running with elevation (as administrator) in your automation environments?

Comment: Try right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Powershell commands are affected by rights and credentials from executing user. There is no reason a PS script has less rights than the user executing the command.

Comment: The script is scheduled to be run with "highest privileges".